# .NET BindingSource.Filter with regular expressions

Tags: c#, .net, regex, bindingsource

i am using a BindingSource.Filter to list only certain elements of the datasource.
especially i use it like this a lot:

```
m_bindingSourceTAnimation.Filter = "Name LIKE '" + FilterText + "'";
```

now my question is, if it is somehow possible to use regular expressions with these filters.

i would especially need multiple wildcard (*) characters like

```
*hello*world*
```

thanks!

Comment: What is the underlying data source? A `DataTable`? A List<T>? etc

Comment: Editing with an alternative...

Comment: yes, it is a "DataTable"

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can query the DataTable with LINQ pretty easily and then you can use a actual Regex within the query to filter it anyway you like.

Something like this...

```
var source = myDataTable.AsEnumerable();

var results = from matchingItem in source
              where Regex.IsMatch(matchingItem.Field<string>("Name"), "<put Regex here>")
              select matchingItem;

//If you need them as a list when you are done (to bind to or something)
var list = results.ToList();
```

This will get you the rows that match based on an actual Regex, I don't know what you need to do with the information, but this would allow you to get the rows based on a Regex.

****Update** - Trying to clarify based on comment

I don't know what you are using this for so I don't have a great context, but from what I can guess you are using a DataTable to data bind to a Grid or something like that.  If this is the case, I think that you should be able to assign "list" from the snippet I put in here as the DataSource (assuming you are using a BindingSource) and I think that it will work.  I don't use DataTables, I usually stick to objects for working with my data so I am not exactly sure how it will handle the list of rows, but I would think that it would work (or be close enough that a little google searching would do it).

Comment: thanks, but i have never used LINQ before. how can i use it inside my C# code where i have the BindingSource?

Answer (score 5):

`BindingSource` relies on [`IBindingListView.Filter`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.ibindinglistview.filter.aspx) for this functionality. The behaviour depends *entirely* on the specific list implementation. Is this a `DataTable`/`DataView`? If so, this maps to [`DataView.RowFilter`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.dataview.rowfilter.aspx), with syntax listed [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datacolumn.expression(vs.71).aspx).

The `DataView` implementation has no regex support, but supports `LIKE` via `*` - i.e. where `FilterText` is something like `"Foo*Bar*"`. At least, that is my understanding.

---

I'm still assuming that you are using `DataTable`/`DataView`... a pragmatic alternative might be to introduce an extra (bool) column for the purpose. Set/clear that marker as the predicate (using a regex or any other complicated logic), and just use the row-filter to say "where set". Not very clean, maybe, but a lot simpler than implementing a custom data-view / binding-source.

---

If you are using objects (rather than `DataTable`), then another option might be the [Dynamic LINQ Library](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/01/07/dynamic-linq-part-1-using-the-linq-dynamic-query-library.aspx). I don't know the full range of what it supports, but it (`Where(string)`) certainly has some / much of the `RowFilter` capability. And since the code is available in the sample project, it is *possible* you could educate it to apply a regex?

Comment: thanks, this almost works, it only does not seem to understand * in the middle of a word but only at the beginning and the end, like this:

    *test*

i would really need it in the middle of a word. :-)

Comment: thanks, i think i understand what you mean, but that would require to make some custom list of all the strings i want to filter and then apply regex on it. is there something for this in .NET already, or will i need to do my own regex?

Comment: Regex is built into .NET, but I didn't really follow the rest of the comment I'm afraid...

Comment: The DataView.RowFilter documentation explicitly states "Wildcards are not allowed in the middle of a string. For example, 'te*xt' is not allowed."

Comment: "The DataView.RowFilter documentation explicitly states "Wildcards are not allowed in the middle of a string.""

thanks for the info. but infact, this is EXACTLY what i would need! :)

Answer (score 1):

The comment below doesn't really work:

*"...a pragmatic alternative might be to introduce an extra (bool) column for the purpose. Set/clear that marker as the predicate (using a regex or any other complicated logic), and just use the row-filter to say "where set". Not very clean, maybe, but a lot simpler than implementing a custom data-view / binding-source."*

When you set the new column this causes the row state to change and you basically end up with the whole table/dataview thinking that it needs to do every row in the next update. 
Not sure how to get around this problem.

Answer (score 1):

I solved this issue by splitting the search string by the wildcard and then created the row filter expression using the split values.

```
Array a = SearchString.Split('*');
string rowFilter = "";

if (a.GetUpperBound(0) == 1)
{

  rowFilter = "(MODEL_NBR like '" + a.GetValue(0).ToString() + "*' AND MODEL_NBR like '*"      + a.GetValue(1).ToString() + "')";

 }
```

If you use multiple wildcards you could create a recursive function that creates the filter expressio

Answer (score 0):

```
    '[Description] Is column name
    Dim SearchStrArr() As String = Split(txtSearch.Text, " ")
    Dim FilterString As String = "" 
    FilterString = String.Join("%' AND [Description] Like '%", SearchStrArr)
    FilterString = "[Description] Like '%" & FilterString & "%'"

    m_bindingSourceTAnimation.Filter = FilterString
```